# VueJS doesn't update the store value in component if a property of the object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My store is working correctly, apart from one thing. Let me show you my code first:

```
const state = {
  category: {
    title: ''
  }
}

const getters = {
  category: state => {
    return state.category
  }
}

const mutations = {
  changeProperty: (state, [val, prop]) => {
    state.category[prop] = val
  }
}

const actions = {
  changeProperty ({ commit }, [val, prop]) {
    commit('changeProperty', [val, prop])
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

And here is my component:

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar
    app
    color="primary"
    dense
  >

    <span>
      {{ JSON.stringify(category) }}
    </span>

    <v-tooltip
      bottom
      v-for="(item, index) in menu"
      :key="index"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn
          color="info"
          small
          class="ml-5" v-on="on"
          @click="changeProp1(item.title)"
          >
          <v-icon left>mdi-{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>  {{ item.title }}
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>{{ item.legende }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>

    <v-tooltip
      bottom
      v-for="(item, index) in menu"
      :key="'a'+ index"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn
          color="info"
          small
          class="ml-5" v-on="on"
          @click="changeProp2(item.title)"
          >
          <v-icon left>mdi-{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>  {{ item.title }}
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>{{ item.legende }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>

  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Buttons',
  methods: {
    changeProp1(title) {
      console.log('TITRE: ' + title)
      this.$store.dispatch('modulename/changeProperty', [title, 'title'])
    },
    changeProp2(title) {
      console.log('TITRE2: ' + title)
      this.$store.dispatch('modulename/changeProperty', [title, 'title2'])
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    menu: [
      { title: 'Title 1', icon: 'content-save', legende: 'Legend 1' },
      { title: 'Title 2', icon: 'download', legende: 'Legend 2' },
      { title: 'Title 3', icon: 'upload', legende: "Legend 3" }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
    category: state => state.category
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

When I click on the first set of buttons, "changeProp1" is correctly called and the variable in the `span` is refreshed.
When I clicked on the second set of buttons, "changeProp2" is correctly called but the variable in the `span` is not refreshed.
The variable in the `span` is not refreshed either when I click on the first set of buttons if the first property remains the same. For example, let's say I have for `category`  `{title: 'Title 1', title2: 'Title2'}`, if I change the value of `title2`, nothing changes, if I change the value of `title`, I have the new values of `title` and `title2` displayed.

My goal is to have the value of `category` refreshed for every property I update.

Thanks in advance, I hope I explained myself well.

**SOLUTION**

Instead of

```
state.category[prop] = val
```

The following line works fine:

```
state.category = Object.assign({},state.category, {[prop]: val})
```

Thanks to the author of the answer I voted for, the explanation is here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: Is `category.title2` declared upfront? [Vue cannot detect property additions.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Comment: Where is ceremonie defined in your store?
Also why are you using JSON.stringify in template ?

Comment: My bad, I updated my variable names.
category.title2 is not declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a reactivity caveat that should go away in vue 3. I'm linking the vue docs, but it applies to vuex too, since vuex just wraps a vue instance.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

The solution is to declare all potential props initially, or use `Vue.set`

Comment: OK, I managed to do what I want, I update my question to give you the "correct answer" vote, because I managed to find a solution thanks to you.